# How to save data from Python to Onedrive Excel

Tags: python, excel, onedrive

I created the script below, which is fully functional, to get prices of cryptocurrencies, and it's saving the results to a local Excel file called 'moedas.xlsx'. I'd like to save the same results to the same file, but putting it on Microsoft OneDrive and I don't know how to connect to OneDrive via Python. Help, please! Thank you!

```
import requests
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

coins = ['bitcoin', 'ethereum', 'singularitynet', 'helium', 'cardano', 'vechain', 'polymath-network', 'binance-coin','kin']

from openpyxl import Workbook
wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.active
ws = wb.active


for coin in coins:
    page = requests.get('https://coinmarketcap.com/pt-br/currencies/' + coin)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'lxml')
    name_of_coin = soup.find('h1', class_='priceHeading').text
    price = soup.find_all('div', class_=re.compile('priceValue'))[0].text[2:]
    char_to_replace = {',': '.', #replaces the . and , from the USD for the appropriate format in R$
                       '.': ','}
    price_corrected = price.translate(str.maketrans(char_to_replace))
    ws.append([name_of_coin, price_corrected])
wb.save('moedas.xlsx')
```

Comment: You don't connect to OneDrive from Python. It should be configured to map to some drive letter on your system, so you can access if from within Python or any other software just like any other drive.